# Select records to sum column to 600

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-cursor

I have a table with a column named "price", if I sum all records in that column, gives me a result of 1000, but i only need to select the necessary ones to get a result of 600, how can I do that?

I've tried to do that with cursors, but it doesn't work

```
declare cursor1 cursor
for select* from SERVICES

open cursor1

while((select SUM(Price) from SERVICES)=600)
begin
  fetch next from cursor1
  select SUM(Price) from SERVICES
end

close cursor1
deallocate cursor1
```

Comment: what if there are multiple combinations of data that sum 600?, what if there's none?

Comment: it is not about combinations, it is more like select random prices to reach 600 or the closest number to 600

Comment: This is the subset sum problem, which is NP-complete, which means calculations heavy enough to question the sanity of implementing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option which demonstrates how you can use a window function

To be clear, the results may not be exactly 600.

**Example**

```
Select *
 From  (
        Select *
              ,RT = sum(Price) over (Order by Price)
         From  YourTable
       ) A
 Where RT<=600
```

Comment: What if the data is 1, 600?

Comment: @SalmanA Then clearly this would not be a solution.  You know full well this could easily be an NP-Hard

Comment: I know that in production the results would not be an exactly amount, but this is exactly what I need, bro. Thanks!!

Comment: @Azael Happy to help